# Initialize datepicker element on header with vuejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I want to always initialize the date-picker element that i have on my header. This is not working on initializing on `mounted` property or on `created` with Vuejs.

Here is my sample code:

```
<template>
    <input type="text" class="datepicker date-input-field-head" placeholder="Any time">
</template>
<script>
import firebase from 'firebase'


export default {

    data: function() {
        return {
            someData: '',
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        $('.datepicker').pickadate({
            selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
            selectYears: 120, // Creates a dropdown of 120 years to control year,
            today: 'Today',
            clear: 'Clear',
            hiddenName: true,
            formatSubmit: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
            close: 'Ok',
            container: '.wrapper-dj-picker',
            closeOnSelect: false // Close upon selecting a date,
        });
    }
}
</script>
```

My header is always showing on my application, i implemented it on my App.vue (tried also with mounted initializing the element there but without success)

I'm really stuck on this problem for hours, and any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you make a live demo for this ?

Comment: Where ? On jsfiddle it doesn't work?

Comment: Yeah, including a working example would help a lot.  I tried to get a pickadate sample working on jsFiddle but I have no idea what files I need to include.  There's [TONs of them...](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/pickadate.js)

Comment: well i use materialize css and js, and vuejs

Comment: Make a live demo of minimal and required.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/upjzwez8/1/

Comment: It looks like your `container` setting causes problems with my fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/7q2agm8p/1/

Comment: @Muli This is not a direct answer to your question, but you may find [this Medium post](https://medium.com/js-dojo/how-to-safely-use-a-jquery-plugin-with-vue-js-786acdfb743b) useful, as the author explains how to use jQuery plugins with Vue and also specifically uses a datepicker as an example.